# Why VBA calling a C DLL breaks while VB calling the same DLL Does not

Tags: vba, dll

I have a VB program that calls a C DLL. I am trying to do the same thing with VBA for Access. The VB code works and the VBA crashs when a call  Call ERPGetFingerprintImage(buff, tam_image). I thinks that the Byte Array interface generates the error.

Any Clue?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the VB code:

```
  Public Class Form1
    Declare Sub ERPInitialize Lib "C:\Desenv\EBioNet\EBioNet\Release\ERPDll.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr)
    Declare Sub ERPStartCapture Lib "C:\Desenv\EBioNet\EBioNet\Release\ERPDll.dll" ()
    Declare Sub ERPIsFingerCaptured Lib "C:\Desenv\EBioNet\EBioNet\Release\ERPDll.dll" ()
    Declare Sub ERPGetFingerprintImage Lib "C:\Desenv\EBioNet\EBioNet\Release\ERPDll.dll" (fingerprintimage As Byte(), ByRef tam_image As Integer)
    Declare Sub ERPGetFingerprintTemplate Lib "C:\Desenv\EBioNet\EBioNet\Release\ERPDll.dll" (fingerprinttemplate As Byte(), ByRef tam_image As Integer)
    Declare Sub ERPGetFingerprintBitMap Lib "C:\Desenv\EBioNet\EBioNet\Release\ERPDll.dll" (ingerprinttemplate As PictureBox, ByRef tam_image As Integer)

    Dim buff() As Byte = New Byte(0) {}
    Dim tam_image As Integer

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Call ERPInitialize(IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call ERPStartCapture()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Call ERPIsFingerCaptured()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        tam_image = 256
        ReDim buff(1000 * 1000)

        Call ERPGetFingerprintImage(buff, tam_image)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Call ERPInitialize(PictureBox1.Handle.ToInt32)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Call ERPGetFingerprintTemplate(buff, tam_image)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Call ERPGetFingerprintBitMap(PictureBox1, tam_image)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The VBA code is below:

```
Option Compare Database
Dim buff() As String

Dim tam_image As Integer

Private Declare Function ERPGetFingerprintImage Lib "C:\Biometria\ERPDll.dll" (ByRef fingerprintimage() As Byte, ByRef tam_image As Integer)


Private Sub Command2_Click()
On Error GoTo Command2_Click_erro

Dim buff() As Byte
tam_image = 256

   ReDim buff(500000)
   Call ERPGetFingerprintImage(buff, tam_image)
Command2_Click_exit:
   Exit Sub
Command2_Click_erro:
MsgBox (Error & " - Rotina ERPGetFingerPrintImage e Rotina ERPGetFingerPrintTemplate")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly passing an array does different things, `Integer` has a different size, and you can't ignore the difference between `Sub` and `Function`.

I need to see the unmanaged signature to be sure, but looking at the VB.NET signature I would rewrite the VBA one as

```
Declare Sub ERPGetFingerprintImage Lib "C:\Desenv\EBioNet\EBioNet\Release\ERPDll.dll" (ByRef fingerprintimage As Byte, ByRef tam_image As Long)
```

To call it you pass the array as

```
dim tam_image as long
tam_image = 256

dim buff() as byte
redim buff(1 to 1000)

ERPGetFingerprintImage buf(lbound(buf)), tam_image
```

Comment: Shouldn't `fingerprintimage` be an array?

Comment: @Comintern Then unmanaged code will receive a pointer to the `SAFEARRAY` structure. Very rarely it is in fact what you want, but almost always unmanaged code expects a plain pointer to a memory buffer. This is achieved in VB6/A by declaring the parameter `byref as byte` and passing the first byte of the buffer. Alternatively you could declare the parameter `byval as long` and pass `varptr(buf(lbound(buf)))`, but I like that less.

Comment: Makes sense.  I missed how you were calling `ERPGetFingerprintImage` in the VBA code.

Comment: fingerprint is a array of bytes

Comment: @Comintern thanks! you mean i have to cjange the plain pointer from char * to VARIANT *?

Comment: I tried to use VARIANT and the problem remains de same.

Comment: Private Declare Function ERPGetFingerprintImage Lib "C:\Biometria\ERPDll.dll" (ByRef fingerprintimage() As Byte, ByRef tam_image As Long)

Comment: @user3358125 I posted the correct signature. `ByRef fingerprintimage As Byte`, not `ByRef fingerprintimage() As Byte`.